# Automatic tool for resolving left-recursion within CFG

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, left-recursion

Though facing the fear that someone might not like my question but does somebody know a useful tool to either

- resolve left recursion or to
- simplify

a context-free grammar automatically ?

I need to resolve a rather long chain of left-recursion in my grammar.

So far I've tried [this](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/images/PLT/PLTelralgorithm.gif) algorithm and [this](http://lab.brainonfire.net/CFG/remove-left-recursion.html) tool. But both are only applicable for smaller grammars and provide practically unusable results (1000's of rules).

Comment: Tool requests are offtopic here. Maybe the new [softwarerecs.SE] is a place for you?

Comment: Pity but I understand the background why tool requests are off-topic here - at least I think I understand (it's to keep the forum clean only with computer science questions and not to spam with other things?) However, from a topic point-of-view it would fit in here since you need tools to do science. In fact most science applications rely on tools such as diagram plotter for interpreting results, a compiler to compile code etc. So maybe one could weaken the tool-restriction-rule a bit or at least think about it? cheers

Comment: We allow questions about tools that are themselves objects of (contemporary) science (in particular research), for example (interactive) theorem provers. Support for these tools is still offtopic, but questions for how and why they work (in a particular way) can be ontopic. Requests for tools (as opposed to algorithms/data structures/...) will almost always be offtopic. In case of doubt, just drop by in [chat]!